# UIImageview is not scaling to its frame when image is set

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uiimageview

[image]

Here I have attached the screenshot that I have worked. I am facing an issue that image view is not scaling to the frame. I have created a custom view within the custom view i have added imageview and set constraints to its parent view (here containerview)

image content mode is scaleAspectFit

```swift
let imageView = makeImageView()
addSubview(imageView)

imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

When I initialise the custom view into the viewcontroller shows like above screenshots. In viewcontroller I am just adding the image to the stackview.

Can you please let me know what should be added?

Comment: What do you want to see differently? The orange is the image view. You told the image view to show the image as "aspect fit". That's exactly what it is doing.

Comment: @HangarRash, Yes you are correct. But image has dynamic sizes and should be shown with aspect ratios(Images will shown as original). In this case I can't set aspectToFill property. Then how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: @Naresh Tired but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to leave the image view's content mode set to `.contentMode = .scaleToFill`.

Then, when you set its `.image`, set a proportional height anchor with:

```
multiplier: img.size.height / img.size.width)
```

Here is an example custom class - I've inset the image view by 8-points on all 4 sides for clarity:

```
class ProportionalImageView: UIView {
    
    public var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            imgView.image = image
            if let img = image {
                proConstraint.isActive = false
                proConstraint = imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: img.size.height / img.size.width)
                proConstraint.isActive = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var proConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    private let imgView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {

        imgView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imgView)
    
        proConstraint = imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            proConstraint,
        ])
        
        backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    }
    
}
```

and an example view controller... vertical stack view containing a "top label" the custom view and a "bottom label". Also loads 3 images - at 300x300, 300x200 and 200x300. Tapping anywhere cycles through to the next image:

```
class ProImageTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let proImageView = ProportionalImageView()
    
    var images: [UIImage] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        ["i300x300", "i200x300", "i300x200"].forEach { sName in
            guard let img = UIImage(named: sName) else {
                fatalError("Could not load image: \(sName)")
            }
            images.append(img)
        }
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
    
        let v1 = UILabel()
        v1.text = "Top Label"
        v1.textAlignment = .center
        v1.backgroundColor = .green
        
        let v2 = UILabel()
        v2.text = "Bottom Label"
        v2.textAlignment = .center
        v2.backgroundColor = .green
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(v1)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(proImageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(v2)

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -60.0),
        ])
        
        nextImage()
    }

    func nextImage() {
        let img = images.removeFirst()
        images.append(img)
        proImageView.image = img
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        nextImage()
    }
    
}
```

Using these three images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It looks like this when running:

[image]

[image]

[image]